# javascrip para hamburguer menu

Tags: javascript

Ola, estou tentando criar um hamburguer menu e para isso eu precisaria mudar um elemento `#headercontainer ul` assim que o hamburguer menu fosse clickado.

Eu utilizei o código JavaScript abaixo

```js
let menuButton = document.querySelector(".menuButton");
let menu = document.querySelector("#headercontainer ul");
menuButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    menu.classList.toggle("open");
});
```

E utilizei o HTML abaixo

```html
<header>
    <div id = "headercontainer">
        <div id = "logoheader">

            <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" " alt="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="menuButton"><a href=“#">☰</a></div> 

        <div id="nav-links" class="menu-top-bar-container">
            <ul id="menu-top-bar" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-176" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-140 current_page_item menu-item-176"><a href="#" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-178" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-178"><a href="#">link2</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-186" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-186"><a href="#">link3</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-187" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-187"><a href="#">link4</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-188" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-188"><a href="#">link5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

</header>
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Bom como seu hamburger está contido num anchor `</a>`, você deve primeiro cancelar o evento de redirecionamento:

```
let menuButton = document.querySelector(".menuButton");
let menu = document.querySelector("#nav-links");
menuButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.classList.toggle("open");
});
```

E pra facilitar o css usa a classe `open` no container do menu, selecionando o `#nav-links`